# Question category suggestion

Tags: discussion

I would like to give a suggestion. It is great that you can ask other developers to revise your code, correct it and give you suggestions. But sometimes, you need help with configuring the best technology or a practice you could use, before starting coding. Such questions are not allowed on Stack Overflow. Why is that and can that be changed? Making a category of questions, which do not contain code but asking for suggestion for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is off-topic for Stack Overflow, which focuses on problems with existing code. Since questions about architecture and design tend to be more subjective, they have been ruled out there.

Questions about architecture and design can *sometimes* be asked on [Software Engineering Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com).

From their [Help Center](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> If you have a question about...
>
> - software development methods and practices
> - requirements, architecture, and design
> - quality assurance and testing
> - configuration management, build, release, and deployment
>
> ...then you're *probably* in the right place to ask your question.

Note that the word "probably" is emphasized!!

Software Engineering SE has had its share of poorly asked questions in the past. So, the site is now moderated strictly, just like Stack Overflow. **You should familiarize yourself with the site before asking there.** Lurk there for a while, spend some time reading its per-site meta, and develop a "gut feeling" for what kind of questions are welcomed there. This takes some time, but it will prevent downvotes and closure.